# The correct way to define regions or sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to define the six regions in the attached example [image: example]
I know that, for example, region 1 can be described by: $$ 4\leq x_1 \leq 5$$ and $$2\leq x_2 \leq 1$$
However, can I define the regions in the form: $$g_i(x)\leq 0  , i =1,2,..,6.$$
Can you help me or give a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a\le x\le b$ iff $(x-a)(x-b)\le 0$.

Comment: This fact is very useful, thanks! Can we have a linear function? in from $$Ax\leq 0$$